# Sitecore 8.1 :- sitecore.context.user not working in multiple CD server

Tags: load-balancing, sitecore8

We are using sitecore 8.1.
After authenticating user from AZURE B2C, we are storing a valid user as a Sitecore Context User and setting custom profile properties into the user object.

we are able to get the properties value when we are in Dev/SIT environment but we are unable to get the values sometimes when the request is shared across the multiple CD servers due to load balancer is enabled.

Is there any configuration we need to be update?

Comment: Are you sure that appropriate custom user profile item exists below '/sitecore/system/Settings/Security/Profiles' folder in core database of CD server?

Comment: This is not a sitecore user , we are using extranet user (end user) to logged in our website.